# Xinput unable to see disabled devices

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, wacom

I am using Ubuntu on a hybrid PC, and to use a wacom pen to draw on it I found my touchscreen and disabled it via the xinput command in terminal. I was able to enable it, too. But when I restarted it, the touchscreen wasn't working and when I write "xinput" in terminal, it didn't show my touchscreen.

By the way, I am using a Samsung ATIV Smart PC Pro 700T, my touchscreen driver's name is "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer".